# Find the index of a string value in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I identify which column(s) in my DataFrame contain a specific string `'foo'`?

#### Sample DataFrame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,42], 'B':['foo','bar','blah'],'C':[3,4,5], 'D':['some','foo','thing']})
```

I want to find `B` and `D` here.

#### I can search for numbers:

If I'm looking for a number (e.g. 42) instead of a string, I can generate a boolean mask like this:

```
>>> ~(df.where(df==42)).isnull().all()

A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
dtype: bool
```

#### but not strings:

```
>>> ~(df.where(df=='foo')).isnull().all()

TypeError: Could not compare ['foo'] with block values
```

I don't want to iterate over each column and row if possible (my actual data is much larger than this example). It feels like there should be a simple and efficient way.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with underlying array data -

```
df.columns[(df.values=='foo').any(0)].tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [209]: df
Out[209]: 
    A     B  C      D
0  10   foo  3   some
1  20   bar  4    foo
2  42  blah  5  thing

In [210]: df.columns[(df.values=='foo').any(0)].tolist()
Out[210]: ['B', 'D']
```

If you are looking for just the column-mask -

```
In [205]: (df.values=='foo').any(0)
Out[205]: array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: The argument 0 in any() here, means axis=0, columns?

Comment: @sheldonzy Yes, means find if `ANY` match along the first axis (axis=0), which is per column.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 `df.values`

```
~(df.where(df.values=='foo')).isnull().all()

Out[91]: 
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
dtype: bool
```

Option 2 `isin`

```
~(df.where(df.isin(['foo']))).isnull().all()
Out[94]: 
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it won't index a str through the syntax you gave. It has to be run as a series of type string to compare it with string, unless I am missing something.

try this

```
~df101.where(df101.isin(['foo'])).isnull().all()
A    False
B     True
C    False
D     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I did not see it before writing :/