# Can I determine which columns in a data frame contain cells that include a specific string within the cell value, without knowing the column or index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains a bunch of entries within each column. However, these entries are just strings of lists of numbers (not proper lists, as python defines them), as such:

```
data = {'name1': ['1456, 1324, 4782', '5428'], 
        'name2': ['7832, 1477, 8092', ''], 
        'name3': ['9496', '7842, 8326'], 
        'name4': ['5532, 1886', '7732, 6512, 9044']}
```

Ideally, the end result from the code would be to determine which columns contain a certain number, so if I was looking for 1477, it would either return True for column name2, or it would return a list of column labels containing that number (so just name2), either output would be viable.

Since the data is organized as such, I can't look for exact equivalence, so I can't use `.isin` or `==`. The other catch is that I don't know where it is in the data frame, so I also can't specify a certain column or index to convert to a series and look through. I've tried and failed to figure a way to use `.loc`, `.contains`, or `.filter` because it seems they work best when you can search for a specific column or index to use. The closest I've gotten was using the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453275/find-the-index-of-a-string-value-in-a-pandas-dataframe). The problem with this was it was looking for an exact match to the string with '==', and was looking for an index, not a column. One last note is that my actual DataFrame contains many more entries than this example, so I'd prefer not to use `for` loops to iterate over each row and column, if possible, however that would technically work if absolutely necessary.

I'll admit that my knowledge of pandas is incredibly limited beyond what posts and blogs I've read, so maybe I'm just overlooking something simple? Hopefully someone has an answer to this that's a bit more efficient than a brute force for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for each column (with `apply`) and identify columns with at least one match using [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r'\b1477\b').any())
```

*NB. the `\b` are regex word boundaries, to ensure `1477` doesn't match `14770` for example.*

Or, with [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split(', ').explode().eq('1477').any())
```

Output:

```
name1    False
name2     True
name3    False
name4    False
dtype: bool
```

Then if you want the list of indices:

```
out.index[out]
# Index(['name2'], dtype='object')
```

Or to slice the matching columns:

```
df.loc[:, out]
```

Comment: While this works perfectly for my code, I'd like to understand it a bit better. How come the index returns the column if the default axis for `.any` is 0 (the index). Does that not correspond to the rows? Additionally, if I were to want to modify this to search the rows and not the columns, why when I use `.any(1)` I get the error: TypeError: Series.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: You should use `any(axis=1)` since this method only accepts keywords now. Regarding the default `axis=0`, it makes sense since the rows are aggregated into one value.